# Equally divide a list of names in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, textjoin

We are using Google Sheets to track a list of about 60 people.  We add and remove some each week.  I am using functions like this to join them into a groups, `=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE,$A$2:$A$15)`

I would like to replace the `$A$2:$A$15` part with something that would take 1/5th of the total list regardless of how long or short it becomes.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group only the first fifth:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE,$A$2:INDEX($A$2:$A,ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A2:A)/5)))
```

or if you want group all:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE,FILTER($A:$A,ROW($A:$A)>=(ROUNDUP(COUNTA($A:$A)/5)*(ROW()-2)+2),ROW($A:$A)<=(ROUNDUP(COUNTA($A:$A)/5)*(ROW()-1)+1)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROW(A2)-1+ROUNDDOWN(COUNTA(A2:A)/5)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

or:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, 
 QUERY(A2:A, "where A is not null limit "&ROUNDDOWN(COUNTA(
 QUERY(A2:A, "where A is not null", 0))/5), 0))
```

[image]